# how can android play video by inputstream

Tags: android, inputstream

I got an input stream from socket about CCTV,but i do not know how to display it as video,is there any APIs?In another words,how can android display CCTV???

my question:I have used a video framework to display a video,which is display by String path.
but what i want is displaying by stream...how can i figure it out???

help me....

```
`void playfunction(){
     String path = "";
     VideoView mVideoView;
     EditText mEditText;
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.url);
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);

//      path="http://dlqncdn.miaopai.com/stream/MVaux41A4lkuWloBbGUGaQ__.mp4";
    path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/cctvwatch.mp4";
  if (path == "") {
        // Tell the user to provide a media file URL/path.
        Toast.makeText(VideoViewDemo.this, "Please edit VideoViewDemo Activity, and set path" + " variable to your media file URL/path", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    } else {
        /*
         * Alternatively,for streaming media you can use
         * mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(URLstring));
         */

        mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        mVideoView.requestFocus();

        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                // optional need Vitamio 4.0
                mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!